# What is wrong with this C# and XAML code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

basically i want to navigate between two pages in my WPF app.

First i tried this.

```
NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
    Page1 page = new Page2();
    nav.Navigate(page);
```

then this

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Page2());
```

Please note that my original page name is sysinfo.xaml and my source page name is entry.xaml.i hust put page1 and page 2 for simplicity
then the reference MSDN example

```
 this.NavigationService.Navigate(new ContentPage());
```

I want to navigate from page 1 to page 2 when my next button is clicked
my next button code

```
<Button Content="Next" Height="30" Name="nextbutton" Width="95" Margin="0,269,408,12" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Click="nextbutton_Click" />
```

My source page c# code

```
 void nextbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
     nav.Navigate(new System.Uri("Page2.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
 }
```

My error is NULLREFERENCEEXCEPTION -Unhandled Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

my full stacktrace

```
  at Crystal_pre_Install.Entry.nextbutton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\monika\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Crystal pre-Install\Crystal pre-Install\Entry.xaml.cs:line 30
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.CrackMouseButtonEventAndReRaiseEvent(DependencyObject sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Crystal_pre_Install.App.Main() in C:\Users\monika\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Crystal pre-Install\Crystal pre-Install\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Could you add the full stacktrace for the exception?

Comment: It looks like `NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this)` returns `null`. In the next line you thus try to invoke a method on a null reference which cases the `NullReferenceException`. For possible reasons why `NavigationService.GetNavigationService()` may return `null` see the REMARKS-section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.getnavigationservice.aspx).

Comment: What kind of class/page your first code is called from? MainWindow? Can you post some information about your startup object, is it uri or a window?

Comment: My startup object is a window.It's forwarded to a page.the problem is i cannot forward to another page(page 2) from page 1 when i click the next button

Comment: I am not posting as an answer as this is untested.  I know when I want to fill a frame with a page in code behind I need to create the page as a URI.  If you have just two pages you could do this with a frame.

Answer (score 3):

I bumped on this thread by accident.
This seems to be a famous question so here's an alternative:

If you are navigating from one WINDOW to another WINDOW, you should be able to do this:

```
Page2 page2 = new Page2();
this.Hide();
page2.showDialog();
```

You could pass a reference to the current page into the constructor of Page2 so you can show the hidden form afterwards like this:

```
//In MainWindow

Page2 page2 = new Page2(this);
this.Hide();
page2.showDialog();



//In Page2

private Window previousWindow;

public Page2(Window pageReference) {
    InitializeComponent();
    previousWindow = pageReference;
    this.Closing += Page_Closing;
}

void Page_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (previousWindow != null)
        previousWindow.Show();
}
```

If you are "navigating" (which is not the correct term), you should do this:

```
this.Content = new Page2();
```

The question may be two years old, but there are still people looking for this, I assume.
I hope this helps.